# Not able to pass List<FilterData> using WCF with wsHttpBinging

Tags: wcf, list, serialization, datacontract, transport

I am not able to pass List using WCF with wsHttpBinging. List is a property of FilterResponse class. 
Getting the following error.

-Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

//Following is the code.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "Abc.Wao.Entity.Response")]
[CollectionDataContract]`

public class FilterResponse : Alcoa.Wao.Entity.Response.Response
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1002:DoNotExposeGenericLists"), DataMember]
    public List<FilterData> FilterData { get; set; }
}


[KnownType(typeof(FilterResponse))]
[CollectionDataContract]
[DataContract(Namespace = "Abc.Wao.Entity.Response")]
public class Response
{
    public Response()
    { }

    [DataMember]
    public string AuthToken { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Fault { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string SessionContext { get; set; }
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode =   ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class WaoService : IWaoService
{

    public FilterResponse GetFilterDetails()
    {
        FilterResponse res = null;
        //Call factory
        res =  Abc.Wao.Factory.CommonFactory.GetFilterDetails();
        return res;
    }
}
```

//------------------------------------------------------

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(FilterResponse))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Response))]
public interface IWaoService
{
   [OperationContract]
   FilterResponse GetFilterDetails();
}
```

---

Comment: [DataContract(Namespace = "Abc.Wao.Entity.Data")]
    public class FilterData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string RegionName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int SiteId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        
    }

Comment: Is there an inner exception or anything in the event viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Your property in the DataContract is missing a DataMember attribute:

```
[DataMember]
public List<FilterData> FilterData { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have mentioned the DataMember attribute as follows. But this is not solving my problem.[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1002:DoNotExposeGenericLists"), DataMember] public IList<FilterData> FilterData { get; set; }